# KryoException: Unable to find class on Linux only

Tags: java, linux, kryo

I get the next exception when de-serializing an object on linux server, while it works fine on my windows PC.

**Exception in thread "main" com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: CLASS_PATH**

The object is serialized and de-serialized locally only (server or pc)
I checked the path on the server and it is the same as CLASS_PATH, with the same upper/lower cases.

Comment: Most likely, your **CLASSPATH** settings are different on your two systems. It doesn't matter if the variable looks the same; the thing is that the real classes on your system need to be there. Besides: is that really the error message - complaining about a missing class called CLASS_PATH?!

Comment: I just do not want to present the real classes/packages names, so I wrote CLASS_PATH. I use the git and maven tools to build the project and the settings are the same on both machines. Is it possible that the problem exists because I have the same class name in a different package?

Comment: Bad idea; as that is confusing. You could be using something like com.whatever.myproduct.mypacke.SomeClass at least. But anyway, then your problem is clear: that one class does **not** exist within your CLASS_PATH on your Linux system.

Comment: Read and understand this here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html then

Comment: There is no a problem with calsspath. I used the kry registration for the class which weren't found, and it worked. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Glad you figured it!

Answer (score 2):

I have classes with the same class names but in the different packages.
Using kryo registration of these classes solves the issue.

**kryo.register(SomeClass.class);**